# How to get livestream tiny URL with YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api, tinyurl

```js
function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.liveStreams.list({
      "part": [
        "snippet,cdn,contentDetails,status"
        //"cdn"
      ],
      "mine": true
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
                
                var responseData = JSON.stringify(response);
                alert(responseData);
                
                //alert(response.result.items);
                
                var itemsArr = response.result.items;
                var itemObj = itemsArr[0];
                alert('streamName = ' + itemObj.cdn.ingestionInfo.streamName);
                
                //alert(responseData.result);
                //var result = responseData.result;
                
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

I am new to YouTube live streaming. I am doing it through my application. I have gone through various question/answers on this portal but couldn't find/understand a way to get it.

Is there any way (with YouTube Data API v3) to get live stream tiny URL (something like `https://youtu.be/OHi8m4o8XeQ`) so that I can share my live stream to my audiences?

I have got a stream key/name (20 character alphanumeric key with four `-` in between) from YouTube Data API v3, that I will use to stream to YouTube.

I am adding one screenshot for reference. I want the tiny url (something like https://youtu.be/someid) in upper right side.

[image: please find the image here]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Afterwards, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63565437/edit) your post, adding to it relevant missing information (without which the other SO users cannot come to your help).

Comment: @stvar i have added an image for reference. Will it be of anyhelp to answer?

Comment: @stvar I have edited my question. Please find the code i used for getting stream key.  I am simply asking that is there any way to get the live stream tiny url (to be shared with my audiences).

Comment: Is your stream [bound to](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams) a broadcast?

Comment: @stvar No, It is not

Comment: Then do [bind it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) and look for the property [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#id).

Comment: @stvar going with your last comment, i followed the steps in the link. I created a livebroadcast, then created a livestream, and then called liveBroadcasts.bind passing those two id(received above). But what about the tiny URL now? I guess It is like https://youtu.be/[livebroadcastId]

Comment: The `id` property should be your *public* video ID (if you made your broadcast public). Then you could share that ID, either by itself, or in the form of the standard URL `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID`, or in the shortened form of `https://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID`.

Comment: Usually, a video ID is of form `^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{11}$`. Does your broadcast ID obey to this regex pattern?

Comment: Yes, I have got an 11 characters value(made up of small and capital letters, no digits) in "id" key when i called liveBroadcasts.insert. I think you are saying me to consider this ID as broadcastId / videoId. and i should use this ID to create the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take your channel url and add `/live` .

Comment: I want to get tiny url like one i mentioned in my question (something like https://youtu.be/SomeAlphanumericId). Is there any way to get it using youtube data api v3? Till now i have livestream's name/key through youtube data api v3.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube's shortened URL associated to a given video -- identified by its ID `VIDEO_ID` -- is of form:

`https://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID`,

where (usually, though not officially documented as such) `VIDEO_ID` obeys to the following regex pattern:

`^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{11}$`.

In the case of live streaming, for to be able to share the shortened URL of one such stream you've created, you should obtain the *video ID* associated to that stream.

That video ID is to be found as the value of the property [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#id) of the [`LiveBroadcasts`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#resource) resource that [is bound to](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) your live stream.