# Get YouTube stream url before broadcasting when you stream with OBS

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, obs

### It is going to be a `YouTube API` question using `JavaScript`. Hold on...

I regularly stream to YouTube using OBS Studio. I do it so, that I click on the "Live broadcast" icon in YouTube Studio.

YouTube Studio: [https://studio.youtube.com/channel/`CHANNEL_ID`](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/%60CHANNEL_ID%60)

The page gets navigated upon clicking to
[https://studio.youtube.com/channel/`CHANNEL_ID`/livestreaming](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/%60CHANNEL_ID%60/livestreaming)

This gets redirected to [https://studio.youtube.com/video/`NEW_VIDEO_ID`/livestreaming](https://studio.youtube.com/video/%60NEW_VIDEO_ID%60/livestreaming)

Here you can edit your streaming settings before the broadcasting starts, like title, description, etc. and you will have a video URL like this:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`NEW_VIDEO_ID`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%60NEW_VIDEO_ID%60)

And the live chat URL: [https://studio.youtube.com/live_chat?is_popout=1&v=`NEW_VIDEO_ID`](https://studio.youtube.com/live_chat?is_popout=1&v=%60NEW_VIDEO_ID%60)

### What I wish to achieve:

I wish to create a simplified webpage, what I can dock into OBS Studio, where I can set up title, description, etc, and when I click on "Create stream" or something like this, it will get the `NEW_VIDEO_ID`, so that I could copy the video URL (what I can share), and also I could open the live chat in OBS Studio without having a separate Chrome window open.

**I guess it is possible through YouTube API.** (But I didn't figure out how.)

I preferably create a static HTML file with JavaScript (so that I wouldn't need to run a server), but I am open to Node.js solutions as well.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here is basically the answer to your question w.r.t. getting your live stream URL: [How to get livestream tiny URL with YouTube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64152800/8327971). That would imply quite a lot of work (create a broadcast, create a live stream, bound the broadcast to the live stream, etc.) The video ID (that you can share with others or use it yourself) is that broadcast's [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#id).