# Trying to find video ID of starting YouTube Streaming Broadcast

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, video-streaming

I am trying to retrieve the video ID (eventually in JavaScript) of the YouTube video that just started streaming from our church.  In testing to see what works and what doesn't, when I try calling

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?eventType=live&part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&type=video&key={API_KEY}'
```

I get back an empty list **until** I go into Studio for the channel and change the setting on the now live video (which is already Public) to something else and then Public again and click Publish.  It is worth noting that in the Live Streaming portion of Studio where the video is set up that it is also marked Public.  This is not something that we could have church volunteers running the broadcast on Sunday do.  Is there either some way to either get the video ID (for certain reasons I don't want to use the [https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel={CHANNEL_ID}](https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=%7BCHANNEL_ID%7D) option) or to publish the new live video either automatically or without requiring an OAuth token?

I am looking to do this so that from our web page, which is on a hosted site that doesn't allow programmatic updates, we would dynamically be able to look up the video ID of the pending (or now actively streaming) live stream being broadcast from the church.  OAuth access to the YouTube APIs isn't a good option, as there are security issues, so that rules out certain options. Some API key searches let you see the ID, but only after the video is published from YouTube Studio, but depending on church volunteers to go into the YouTube channel and make updates there as the video is starting is also not a valid option in this case.

We could do the video ID lookup and update the web page manually if that is the only option, but my hope was that there would be *some* way that this could be done from JavaScript so that we could always know that the web page was pointing to the right video so that we don't have to rely on someone remembering to (or being able to) update the web page or do some similar update each week.

Comment: This is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64152800/8327971) to your question: the video ID of a live stream is the [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#id) of the live broadcast that is bound to that live stream.

Comment: Yes, I know what the ID is and how to look it up from the web page.  What I'm looking for is how (from JavaScript) I can locate this value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, the [`LiveBroadcasts.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) API endpoint has a request parameter that allows you to retrieve a set of [LiveBroadcast resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#resource-representation) objects pertaining to the live broadcasts that belong to the authenticated user (which objects contain, among other info, the IDs of your interest):

> [**`mine`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#mine) (boolean)
>
> The `mine` parameter can be used to instruct the API to only return broadcasts owned by the authenticated user. Set the parameter value to `true` to only retrieve your own broadcasts.

Note that to invoke this endpoint, you have to have proper authorization; that is to say that you have to have obtained valid credentials upon running to successful completion an OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flow. Hence you have to pass on to the endpoint a valid access token that has among its scopes at least one of those [specified by the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#auth).

The `curl` call to `LiveBroadcast.list` at a `bash` command line prompt would look like:

```bash
$ curl \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id&fields=items/id&maxResults=50&mine=true'
```

where `$ACCESS_TOKEN` is an environment variable that is set to a valid access token (as mentioned above).

For what concerns a JavaScript implementation of this endpoint call, there are several possible solutions, mainly depending on the type of your app: a desktop app or a web app.

If using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), you'll have to mimic closely the `curl` call above:

```js
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id&fields=items/id&maxResults=50&mine=true', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
  }
})
```

where the variable `access_token` contains your valid access token.

For what concerns a Javascript `GAPI` (i.e. Google’s Client Library for Browser-side JavaScript) implementation, the code would look like shown below (for a broader context look into this sample source file from Google: [`analytics_codelab.js`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/analytics_codelab.js)):

```
function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    getMyLiveBroadcasts();
  });
}

function getMyLiveBroadcasts() {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.liveBroadcasts.list({
    part: 'id',
    fields: 'items/id',
    mine: true,
    maxResults: 50
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    if ('error' in response) {
      displayMessage(response.error.message);
    } else {
      // process each response.items[k].id
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

Note that each piece of code above uses the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to obtain from `LiveBroadcasts.list` only the broadcast's ID info (it is always good to ask from the API only the info that is of actual use).

Comment: My concern with a method that requires the OAuth token is that this would be part of our church website that would allow visitors to view a church service online by looking up the current video.  So (as I understand it) we would either have to have a long life token that was embedded into our website in some manner (and would have to be updated when the token expired) or someone with a login would have to log in to get a token.  If that is not the case then I OAuth token is not the obstacle I thought.  Otherwise, I was looking for being able to use the API key for calls to the YouTube API.

Comment: @G. Taylor: unfortunately, `LiveBroadcasts.list` do require OAuth authorization. There's no way to avoid the OAuth flow and the management of refresh tokens and access tokens. On the other hand, the (long-lived) refresh tokens are a kind of tokens that pertain to desktop apps only. To web apps, one uses only (short-lived) access tokens, that are obtained upon running to successful completion a simplified OAuth flow, named the [*implicit grant flow*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps).

Comment: @G. Taylor: The API keys work with `Search.list` only, but in an awkward manner (that you described within your question above).

Comment: Yes, that was why I was looking at the search API.  I knew that we would not want to embed a long-lived token in the website, but we also don't want to require visitors to our church to have to log in with a Google account to attend a church service online.  This was why I was looking for a solution that did not require an OAuth token, as I mentioned.

Comment: @G. Taylor: But your app could well be ran by the person that starts the live broadcast (or even only extract manually that video ID from YouTube Studio); then make the respective video ID persistent on a server such that your website to only query from that server the stored (current) video ID.

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this @stvar, but it looks like I still can't quite get what I'm looking for.

Comment: I thought about something along those lines as well, but then if someone has to do something every week to make the website work, then why not just manually update the website with the new link each week and avoid the coding?    I'm looking to be able to do this cleanly, from the website, without requiring a website visitor to log in.

Comment: @G. Taylor: If your site is updated each time a live broadcast is to be issued then the things are much more simple: just embed that broadcast's ID within the website code itself (no need to query the ID dinamically).

Comment: That's what we were doing.  I was looking to avoid manually updating the website by having the site make the queries to get the ID.

Comment: @G. Taylor: Under the assumption that you (or someone else for that matter) has to manually (quote) *do something every week to make the website work*, it still make sense to write your (small) desktop app (that uses long-lived refresh tokens) for to query the API for the current ID, for to, then, update the website *programmatically* (i.e. without *effective manual* intervention in the website's source code). That's something like half-manual (a person has to run your desktop app), but, at the same time, is half-automatic since the respective individual will not mangle the website's code.

Comment: @G. Taylor: Instead of using `Search.list` to query for the most recent live stream of your channel and, at the same time, to use only API keys (no OAuth, no refresh and access tokens), you may well employ the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint queried with its request parameter [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) set to the ID of your uploads playlist. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63811627/8327971).

Comment: @ G.Taylor:  I'm assuming that using this latter endpoint will avoid the awkward dance your described in your original post.

Comment: @G. Taylor: Now, if you decide to go this route (of dynamically calling `PlaylistItems.list`), don't forget to apply restrictions through Google developers console to the API key you'll gonna embed within your website's source code; that for to prevent others to use your key: have your key be usable on your website only.

Comment: Hi @stvar, thanks for another possible workaround.  Unfortunately YouTube makes this a similar dance, as live streams aren't a playlist in the Channel search.  I can add a Playlist to the channel, but YouTube has taken away the "auto add" feature, so the stream would still have to be manually added to the playlist.

Comment: @G. Taylor: I think you got me wrong. All channel have an auto-generated auto-updated playlist: one that contains all the uploaded videos of a channel. Usually, a channel ID and its corresponding uploads playlist ID are related by `s/^UC([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{22})$/UU\1/`. My assumption was the following: once you create a live broadcast (thus upon a newly created live stream gets an associated video ID), the uploads playlist gets automatically updated to list that new video ID (which is associated to your new live stream).

Comment: @G. Taylor: It seems you're right. I picked up a random channel (through YouTube website's search) that has a live stream running: its uploads playlist does not list the currently running live stream. This is unexpected API behavior. At a later moment, I'll look it up further on SO and somewhere else to learn why this is the way it is.